# connected vs completely connected graph

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, random-graphs

I'm reading [On random graphs](http://snap.stanford.edu/class/cs224w-readings/erdos59random.pdf) by Erdos and Renyi and they define the completely connected graph as the graph that effectively contains all vertices $P_1,\dots P_n$ (has no isolated points) and is connected in the ordinary sense.

I dont see how being completely connected is stronger than being connected in the ordinary sense. Do they not mean

> "and is connected in the ordinary sense"

as

> "and in addition, has the property of being connected in the ordinary sense".

?

In other words: is there a (classically) connected graph which is not completely connected (i.e. which does not contain all points)? Or maybe that was the definition of connected back then: being one connected component plus some single vertices?

Comment: In this context, *completely connected* signifies, that the selected random graph is not only connected, but also contains all $n$ vertices.

Comment: *Completely connected* is strongly related to the clique $K_n.$ 
An alternative formulation can be: **a connected subgraph of $K_n$ which contains all vertices of $K_n$ is completely connected.**
If you choose a connected subgraph not containing all the vertices of $K_n,$ this subgraph is connected, but is not completely connected.

Comment: It seems they are defining the "effective set of vertices" of the graph to be the vertices which appear in at least one of the chosen edges, and that the graph is "connected" as long as each pair of effective vertices is connected by a path. So, basically what you said in your last sentence.